# Unexpected behavior of pre and post increment/decrement in cpp

Tags: c++

I am learning "pre-increment and post increment" in c++ and following code is showing unexpected behavior in following code-->

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a =10;
    cout << ((++a)*(a++)) << endl; 
}
```

Its O/P is = 132 in VS Code.
But in somewhere it shows 121.
**What is the reason of this unexpected behavior**

I tried to find the solution but not get the solution yet that what is the reason but somewhere I heard about unexpected sequence in cpp as an reason.

Comment: What behavior did you expect (and why)?

Comment: You cannot do 2 increments in the same expression.

Comment: @Eugene Depends on what you're incrementing and in what expression.

Comment: @Eugene Yes you can. You can do as many as you like. Try it before commenting further.

Comment: You don't have any reason to expect any specific behaviour, as it is undefined.

Comment: @user207421 for "cannot" read "must not under pain of undefined behaviour"

Comment: @Caleth UB is certainly to be avoided, but merely counting things is just cargo cult programming.

Comment: @user207421 "if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this document places no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to operations preceding the first undefined operation)." [intro.abstract](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#5). "Try it and see" is invalid advice for C++, it is not amenable to the scientific method w.r.t. undefined behaviour. A conforming implementation need not output a number when running that program

Comment: @Caleb What you actually wrote was ‘cannot’, and that is what I commented on.